Is it possible to change an on-prem SharePoint SE farm name?
We have several on-prem SharePoint SE farms.  The farms were created with generic names based on the config database name (e.g., (get-spfarm).Name shows DR_Config).  We'd like to change the farm names to something more relatable, like Prod_Farm, Dev_Farm, etc.  Is this possible without doing a major reconfiguration of the farm?
Tried asking the question on learn.microsoft.com, but their new Captcha setup is absurd.

I actually found the answer on another site (SpiceWorks).  It's just a couple lines of PowerShell code:
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.Name = "SP_DEV_Farm"
$farm.Update()

